# syncfusion rich text box control tools section hiding when updating the content from external file

Tags: angular, rich-text-editor, ej2-syncfusion

I am exploring the syncfusion richtext editor control using angular for new development purpose. In one scenario I need to upload content from the external file upload, that time richtext box tools section all hidden by automatically.

1. In initial page load all tools are visible in page.

[Initial Load view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9leo.jpg)

2. When upload the content from the external file upload tools section are gone.

[Tools missing after update the content with external file text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzufg.jpg)

in html file I have below code where I am adding "fileContent"

```
 <ejs-richtexteditor
    #syncRTE
    id="defaultRTE"
    [toolbarSettings]="tools"
    [quickToolbarSettings]="quickTools"
    [fileManagerSettings]="fileManagerSettings"
    [innerHtml]="fileContent"
  >
  </ejs-richtexteditor>
```

If I use any constant html from component its not hiding the tools section.

```
 fileContent: SafeHtml = `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <title></title>
<body></body>
</html
```

Problem is when I try to update fileContent  from the file upload scenario tools section in the syncfusion richtext box controls are missing.

```
  onUpload() {
    let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    myReader.onloadend = () => {
      let str = myReader.result?.toString() || '';
      this.fileContent = str;
    };
    myReader.readAsText(this.file);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved by adding ngModel instead of InnerHTML to bind the value.

```
  <ejs-richtexteditor
    #syncRTE
    id="defaultRTE"
    [toolbarSettings]="tools"
    [quickToolbarSettings]="quickTools"
    [fileManagerSettings]="fileManagerSettings"
    [(ngModel)]="fileContent"
  >
  </ejs-richtexteditor>
```